# How to delete a subdirectory from a URL?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I'm trying to turn my website from this:

> http://profe5.com/Profe5-Web/public_html/login.html

To this:

> http://profe5.com/login

I've been struggling to do this, but whenever I run it I get 404 error!

This is my htaccess:

```
    DirectoryIndex Profe5-Web
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^profe5\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://profe5.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^Profe5-Web/public_html/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

It would be so awesome if you guys could help me!
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your complete .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex Profe5-Web
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^profe5\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://profe5.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+Profe5-Web/public_html/([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ Profe5-Web/public_html/$1.html [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This works almost right, the only problem about this, is that now the linked files wont load. For example the css files and JS files are not found!

Comment: For css, js not loading issue, solution is simple, just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Answer (score 0):

you might consider instead doing this via a virtual host; check with your hosting company about setting it up

Answer (score 0):

If you want `/login` to map to `Profe5-Web/public_html/login.html` - try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ Profe5-Web/public_html/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

The RewriteRule you already have, `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [R=301,L]` will map `/login` to `/login.html`, which doesn't seem to do what you need it to.